# Dozer nested class field to flat Map.class mapping using Dozer API

Tags: java, dozer

I'm trying to make Dozer map my classes:

```
public class A {
  private B someB;
  private String someAText;
}

public class B {
  private String someBText;
}
```

to a resulting `Map.class` like the following:

```
"someAText" => "someATextValue"
"someBText" => "someBTextValue"
```

.

That is, I'm trying to specify nested class' field mapping to a flat `Map` key destination. I'm using Dozer by Java API, not xml. I wasn't able to find appropriate builder configuration to manage this. Base code is something like:

```
beanMappingBuilder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    mapping(B.class, Map.class, TypeMappingOptions.oneWay(), mapNull(true));
    mapping(A.class, Map.class, TypeMappingOptions.oneWay(), mapNull(true));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the following configuration:

```
beanMappingBuilder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    // 'A > Map' mapping
    mapping(A.class, Map.class, TypeMappingOptions.oneWay(), TypeMappingOptions.mapNull(true))
      .fields("someAText", "someATextValue")
      .fields("someB.someBText", "someBTextValue");

    // 'B > Map' mapping
    mapping(B.class, Map.class, TypeMappingOptions.oneWay(), TypeMappingOptions.mapNull(true))
      .fields("someBText", "someBTextValue");
  }
}
```